# Integrate Python Cloud code and Local Machine

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

So, I want to do style transfer, and I have the code for it. But my pc isnt that good, dont have a CUDA GPU either. I was wondering if there was a way I could upload the code to some cloud service like Google Colab, run the code, and return image outputs on my pc. All this automatically. Anyone knows of such a thing? Does Google support this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows, you can download "Google Drive Backup and Sync" and easily do that. Mount Google Drive to your colab instance and use the "image output folder" as a folder in your Google Drive and Sync that folder with your PC. In case you are using Linux, use rclone to do the same.

I have been using this for quite some time now.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

There is already a style-transfer example here.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/lucid/blob/master/notebooks/differentiable-parameterizations/style_transfer_2d.ipynb